# CanCan abilities working in application but not in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, cancan

I have the following definition in my ability.rb file:

```
    can :index, Call, :country_id => user.countries
```

I am trying to only index Calls whose country_id is in current user's countries array.

This seems to be working when I try it: It only shows me calls that have been tagged by countries that the current_user is a member of.

However, I have the following test which I can't seem to get to pass:

```
  before :each do
    # Users
    @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true)
  end

  it "should show the call index page with just calls that have the same country tags as them" do
    anotheruser1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    anotheruserscall1 = FactoryGirl.create(:call, user_id: anotheruser1.id)
    anotheruser2 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    anotheruserscall2 = FactoryGirl.create(:call, user_id: anotheruser2.id)
    @admin.countries << anotheruserscall1.country
    ability = Ability.new(@admin)
    ability.should be_able_to(:index, anotheruserscall1)
    ability.should_not be_able_to(:index, anotheruserscall2)
  end
```

But I get a failure:

```
Failures:

  1) Admin ability should show the call index page with just calls that have the same country tags as them
     Failure/Error: ability.should be_able_to(:index, anotheruserscall1)
       expected to be able to :index #<Call id: 1, subject: "Natus qui fuga ut.", description: "Consequatur aut veritatis earum dolor. Reprehenderi...", from: "2012-10-25 18:43:23", to: "2012-10-25 19:43:23", user_id: 7, status: "Tentative", created_at: "2012-10-29 13:41:07", updated_at: "2012-10-29 13:41:07", expert_id: nil, country_id: 1>
     # ./spec/models/ability_spec.rb:291:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed this by passing the details in as a block as follows:

```
    can :index, Call, ["country_id IN (?)", user.countries] do |call|
      user.countries.include?(call.country)
    end
```